# Router guard runing before pinia store

Tags: firebase, vuejs3, vue-router, pinia

I am using:

```
vue@3.2.47
pinia@2.0.35
vue-router@4.1.6
```

I am working with Firebase and I use a pinia Store for the authentication. The way I am doing it as of now is:

1. I have a pinia store called storeAuth.ts with following code (part of the code):

```js
...

export const useStoreAuth = defineStore('storeAuth', () => {
  const user = ref(null)
  const loading = ref(false)
  const errorMessage = ref("")
  const successMessage = ref("")
  const router = useRouter()

  const init = () => {
    onAuthStateChanged(auth, (firebaseUser) => {  
      if (firebaseUser) {
        user.value = {}
        user.value.id = firebaseUser.uid
        user.value.email = firebaseUser.email
        console.log('logged in:',user);
      } else {
        user.value = null
        //console.log('logged out');
      }
    });
  }
...
const loginUser = (credentials) => {
    successMessage.value = ""
    errorMessage.value = ""
    loading.value = true

    signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, credentials.email, credentials.password).then((userCredential) => {
      loading.value = false
      const firebaseUser = userCredential.user;
      router.push('/')
    }).catch((error) => {
      loading.value = false
      //console.log('Error while logging in:',error.message);
      switch (error.code) {
        case 'auth/user-not-found':
          errorMessage.value = "Email and/or password incorrect"
          break;

        case 'auth/wrong-password':
          errorMessage.value = "Email and/or password incorrect"
          break;

        case 'auth/too-many-requests':
          errorMessage.value = "Too many requests. Please reset your password"
          break;

        default:
          errorMessage.value = "There was an error during login"
          break;
      }
    });
  }
...
```

So I call the function loginUser with my credentials and then I am logged in.

Now I would like to use route guards in order to prevent going to the login page when user is signed in. I tried to do it getting the user from the pinia store as I am storing the value in a user variable in my pinia store in the init function. But it is always null when entering in the router/index.ts . So I have tried the following approach :
I enter this following config in my router file :

```js
let currentUser = null

const getCurrentUser = async () => {
  return new Promise<void>((resolve) => {
    onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
      currentUser = user
      resolve()
    })
  })
}

const setupNavigationGuards = async () => {
  await getCurrentUser()

  router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
    currentUser = auth.currentUser

    if (currentUser && (to.name === 'signin' || to.name === 'register')) {
      next({ name: 'home' })
    } else {
      next()
    }
  })
}

// Call the setupNavigationGuards function
setupNavigationGuards()
```

But it is not working and on top of that I would prefer to use the user from my pinia and not the user from Firebase because I would like also to add some roles and show menus to the admins only...

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to refactor my init function into a Promise:
In my storeAuth, the init function looks like this:

```
const init = () => {
      return new Promise((resolve) => {
      onAuthStateChanged(
        auth,
        (firebaseUser) => {
          if (firebaseUser) {
            user.value = {}
            user.value.id = firebaseUser.uid
            user.value.email = firebaseUser.email
            //console.log('logged in:',user.value);
          } else {
            user.value = null
            //console.log('logged out');
          }
          resolve(user.value)
        }
      )
    })
  }
```

and in my router index file, I call it like this:

```
router.beforeEach(async (to) => {
  const storeAuth = useStoreAuth()
  await storeAuth.init()  
  
  if (storeAuth.user && (to.name === 'signin' || to.name === 'register')) {
    return { name: 'home'}
  } else {
    return
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the correct user value from your store you have to call your store's `useStoreAuth` function from *inside* the route guard.

```js
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  const store = useStoreAuth()

  if (store.user && (to.name === 'signin' || to.name === 'register')) {
    next({ name: 'home' })
  } else {
    next()
  }
})
```

Comment: I just tried your code and it is not redirecting. I have logged the store.user and it is null. I have the init function and a log for that and if I use a log in the router.beforeEach function, i can see that it is showing null before showing the log of the assignment of the user...